# XCode: Stack Size Limit on Multidimensional Array

Tags: c++, xcode, multidimensional-array, stack-size

i have some complex classes in my xcode project (below a generic example)
and it seems I have hit some sort of data size limit.
the array sizes I need do not work, if I reduze the array sizes the code works (so no programming errors), but it is too small for what I planned.

reading through the internet I figured out it must be a problem with stack size and most of the solutions say "convert your static arrays to dynamic arrays".

but (1) that is not that easy with multidimensional arrays (some up to 5 to 10 dimensions as they monitor multiple independent variables and each combination is possible)
and (2) are most of the arrays nested in several classes, making it even worse.

I thought already of reducing the data

- int instead of long with some intelligent transposition...
- change resolution of c (0-100%) into steps of 10% (so [100] reduces to [10])

but on one hand this might jeopardize the overall results and on the other is the project still at the start so it will grow in the next month... this array size problem will come back sooner or later...

here I generalized the code showing a 4 dimensional array (2x 2D).
I guess most professional programs use arrays that are even bigger.
so there must be a way to make this works...

```
//.h
class StatisticTable
{
public:
    long Array1 [100][50];
    long Array2 [100][50];
    long Array3 [100][140];
};

class Statistic
{
public:
    void WriteStatistic(short Parameter_a, short Parameter_b,
                        short Parameter_c, short Parameter_d);
    short ReadStatistic(short Parameter_a, short Parameter_b,
                        short Parameter_c, short Parameter_d);

private:
    StatisticTable Table[16][8];
};
```

---

```
//.cpp
void WriteStatistic(short a, short b, short c, short d)
{
    for (int i=0; i<d,   i++) {Table[a][b].Array1[c][i]++;}
    for (int i=d; i<50,  i++) {Table[a][b].Array2[c][i]++;}

    //write some more stuff

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use heap allocation instead of stack allocation?

As suggested, using std::unique_ptr:

```
auto const ptr = std::unique_ptr<StatisticTable>(new StatisticTable()).get(); // heap allocated and deleted automatically when obj goes out of scope
```

---

I.e.

```
auto obj = new StatisticTable(); // heap allocation, allocate reference to new StatisticTable object on heap
// code
delete obj; // release heap allocated object
```

vs.

```
auto x = StatisticTable() // stack allocation
```

Comment: "auto x = new *StatisticTable();" and "delete &new;" 
both get "error, expected a type" ... "auto x = *new StatisticTable();" is accepted by the xcode compiler (and triggers the correct sub functions)
but "delete &x;" gets "error, pointer being freed was not allocated"

Comment: This works for me: `class MyClass
{
 
};
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
 auto obj = *new MyClass();
 delete &obj ;
}
`

Comment: It should be `delete &x;` not `delete &new`.

Comment: Maybe not an allocation problem after all. But in any case, you must allocate large objects from the heap using `new`/`delete`.  It's possible you are writing past the end of your array bounds. In Xcode, you should turn on address sanitization. (Look in Scheme settings, Diagnostics tab, check "Enable Address Sanitizer")

Comment: your MyClass example now looks exactly how I corrected your code above ("*new" instead of "*MyClass" and "&obj" instead of "&new")... but I get errors on the "&obj" saying "pointer was not allocated"... and if I increase the arrays in MyClass I get the same fault as before

Comment: You don't use &obj. I will update my answer. Also, did you turn on address sanitization? Your error is not due to a stack overflow.

Comment: now it works: your asterisk was wrong (auto * obj)... I corrected it and now I can have arrays as big as I wish... thank you

Comment: @RichardHodges I don't C++. What 's unique_ptr. Perhaps provide an answer?

Comment: unique pointer... first time I hear of it... sounds like a heap allocation variable that has a constructor/destructor included... http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr

Comment: It's a stack-allocated container to a pointer. When it goes out of scope and is deallocated, the pointer is deleted. So you can allocate without having to remember to `delete`